# Add remove fields dynamically using contact form 7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to add or remove fields dynamically like jQuery like below link for my form. I used contact form 7 plugin to display form. Is there is any plugin related to it?

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) plugin. There's an easy to follow [tutorial](http://bdwm.be/wpcf7cf/how-to-set-up-conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7/) on how to setup a conditional form.

```
Which fields would you like to view? [select pick-fields "Basic fields" "Advanced fields" "All fields"]

[group basic-fields]
<fieldset>
<legend>Basic Fields</legend>

Your name
[text name]

Your email
[text email]
</fieldset>

[/group]
[group advanced-fields]

<fieldset>
<legend>Advanced Fields</legend>

Your operating system
[select pick-os "Windows" "Mac" "Linux" "Android" "iOS" "Other"]
[group other][text other_os][/group]

Some advanced fields
[text adv]
</fieldset>

[/group]
```

Comment: I will try and let you know